# invalid column name RoleId and UserId

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

When I try to create a user with the following code I get the following exception.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model, string returnurl) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.Emailaddress, model.Password, propertyValues: new {
            Firstname = model.Firstname,
            Lastname = model.Lastname,
            Activated = true
        });
        Roles.AddUserToRoles(model.Emailaddress, Roles.GetAllRoles()); 
        return RedirectToAction("Login", new { returnurl = returnurl });
    }
    return View(model);
}

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException wurde nicht von Benutzercode behandelt.
  HResult=-2146232060
  Message=Invalid column name 'RoleId'.
Invalid column name 'UserId'.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  Class=16
  LineNumber=1
  Number=207
  Procedure=""
  Server=(LocalDb)\v11.0
  State=1
  StackTrace:
       bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
       bei System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
       bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
       bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
       bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
       bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
       bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
       bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
       bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
       bei System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
       bei WebMatrix.Data.Database.<QueryInternal>d__0.MoveNext()
       bei System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       bei WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseWrapper.QuerySingle(String commandText, Object[] parameters)
       bei WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider.IsUserInRole(String username, String roleName)
       bei WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider.AddUsersToRoles(String[] usernames, String[] roleNames)
       bei System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRoles(String username, String[] roleNames)
       bei Coding.Lizards.Video.Manager.Web.Controllers.AccountController.Register(RegisterModel model, String returnurl) in c:\Users\Kirk\Documents\Bitbucket\video-and-stats-manger-webapp\video-and-stats-manager\Coding.Lizards.Video.Manager.Web\Controllers\AccountController.cs:Zeile 61.
       bei lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       bei System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       bei System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       bei System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
       bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
       bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
       bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End[TResult](IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag)
       bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
       bei System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
  InnerException:
```

This is how my SQL script looks like

```
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all tables
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating table 'User'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [UserId] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Firstname] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Lastname] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Emailaddress] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Activated] bit  NOT NULL,
    [Profilepicture] varbinary(max)  NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'webpages_Membership'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Membership] (
    [UserId] int  NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] datetime  NULL,
    [ConfirmationToken] nvarchar(128)  NULL,
    [IsConfirmed] bit  NULL,
    [LastPasswordFailureDate] datetime  NULL,
    [PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess] int  NOT NULL,
    [Password] nvarchar(128)  NOT NULL,
    [PasswordChangedDate] datetime  NULL,
    [PasswordSalt] nvarchar(128)  NOT NULL,
    [PasswordVerificationToken] nvarchar(128)  NULL,
    [PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate] datetime  NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'webpages_OAuthMembership'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_OAuthMembership] (
    [Provider] nvarchar(30)  NOT NULL,
    [ProviderUserId] nvarchar(100)  NOT NULL,
    [UserId] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'webpages_Roles'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Roles] (
    [RoleId] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RoleName] nvarchar(256)  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'Video'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Video] (
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Recordingdate] datetime  NOT NULL,
    [SessionHash] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Filename] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Description] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [Groups_ID] int  NOT NULL,
    [Creator_UserId] int  NOT NULL,
    [Category_ID] int  NOT NULL,
    [Opponent_ID] int  NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'VideoViewcount'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VideoViewcount] (
    [ID] bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Viewtime] datetime  NOT NULL,
    [Video_ID] int  NOT NULL,
    [User_UserId] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'VideoComment'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VideoComment] (
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Content] nvarchar(600)  NOT NULL,
    [Created] datetime  NOT NULL,
    [Creator_UserId] int  NOT NULL,
    [Video_ID] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'Presence'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Presence] (
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Day] datetime  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'Groups'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Groups] (
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Description] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Creator_UserId] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'File'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[File] (
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Filename] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Created] datetime  NOT NULL,
    [Type] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Title] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Description] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Group_ID] int  NOT NULL,
    [Creator_UserId] int  NOT NULL,
    [Folder_ID] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'FileViewcount'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FileViewcount] (
    [ID] bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Viewtime] datetime  NOT NULL,
    [File_ID] int  NOT NULL,
    [User_UserId] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'FileFolder'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FileFolder] (
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [IsPrivate] bit  NOT NULL,
    [Creator_UserId] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'FileComment'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FileComment] (
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Content] nvarchar(600)  NOT NULL,
    [Created] datetime  NOT NULL,
    [File_ID] int  NOT NULL,
    [Creator_UserId] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'VideoCategory'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VideoCategory] (
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [IsPrivate] bit  NOT NULL,
    [Creator_UserId] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'Opponent'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Opponent] (
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Creator_UserId] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'News'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[News] (
    [ID] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Content] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Created] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Creator_UserId] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'webpages_UsersInRoles'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles] (
    [webpages_Roles_RoleId] int  NOT NULL,
    [UserProfile_UserId] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'UserGroup'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserGroup] (
    [Members_UserId] int  NOT NULL,
    [Groups_ID] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'AbsentUsers'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AbsentUsers] (
    [AbsentUsers_UserId] int  NOT NULL,
    [AbsentDays_ID] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'PresentUsers'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PresentUsers] (
    [PresentUsers_UserId] int  NOT NULL,
    [PresentDays_ID] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- Creating table 'ExcusedUsers'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExcusedUsers] (
    [ExcusedUsers_UserId] int  NOT NULL,
    [ExcusedDays_ID] int  NOT NULL
);
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all PRIMARY KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating primary key on [UserId] in table 'User'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_User]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [UserId] in table 'webpages_Membership'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Membership]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_webpages_Membership]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [Provider], [ProviderUserId] in table 'webpages_OAuthMembership'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[webpages_OAuthMembership]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_webpages_OAuthMembership]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Provider], [ProviderUserId] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [RoleId] in table 'webpages_Roles'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Roles]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_webpages_Roles]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RoleId] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [ID] in table 'Video'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Video]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Video]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [ID] in table 'VideoViewcount'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VideoViewcount]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_VideoViewcount]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [ID] in table 'VideoComment'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VideoComment]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_VideoComment]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [ID] in table 'Presence'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Presence]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Presence]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [ID] in table 'Groups'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Groups]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Groups]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [ID] in table 'File'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[File]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_File]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [ID] in table 'FileViewcount'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FileViewcount]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_FileViewcount]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [ID] in table 'FileFolder'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FileFolder]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_FileFolder]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [ID] in table 'FileComment'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FileComment]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_FileComment]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [ID] in table 'VideoCategory'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VideoCategory]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_VideoCategory]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [ID] in table 'Opponent'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Opponent]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Opponent]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [ID] in table 'News'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[News]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_News]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [webpages_Roles_RoleId], [UserProfile_UserId] in table 'webpages_UsersInRoles'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_webpages_UsersInRoles]
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([webpages_Roles_RoleId], [UserProfile_UserId] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [Members_UserId], [Groups_ID] in table 'UserGroup'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserGroup]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_UserGroup]
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Members_UserId], [Groups_ID] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [AbsentUsers_UserId], [AbsentDays_ID] in table 'AbsentUsers'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AbsentUsers]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_AbsentUsers]
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([AbsentUsers_UserId], [AbsentDays_ID] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [PresentUsers_UserId], [PresentDays_ID] in table 'PresentUsers'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PresentUsers]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_PresentUsers]
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([PresentUsers_UserId], [PresentDays_ID] ASC);
GO

-- Creating primary key on [ExcusedUsers_UserId], [ExcusedDays_ID] in table 'ExcusedUsers'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExcusedUsers]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_ExcusedUsers]
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([ExcusedUsers_UserId], [ExcusedDays_ID] ASC);
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Creating all FOREIGN KEY constraints
-- --------------------------------------------------

-- Creating foreign key on [webpages_Roles_RoleId] in table 'webpages_UsersInRoles'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_webpages_UsersInRoles_webpages_Roles]
    FOREIGN KEY ([webpages_Roles_RoleId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[webpages_Roles]
        ([RoleId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [UserProfile_UserId] in table 'webpages_UsersInRoles'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_webpages_UsersInRoles_UserProfile]
    FOREIGN KEY ([UserProfile_UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User]
        ([UserId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_webpages_UsersInRoles_UserProfile'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_webpages_UsersInRoles_UserProfile]
ON [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles]
    ([UserProfile_UserId]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Video_ID] in table 'VideoViewcount'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VideoViewcount]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_VideoViewcountVideo]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Video_ID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Video]
        ([ID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_VideoViewcountVideo'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_VideoViewcountVideo]
ON [dbo].[VideoViewcount]
    ([Video_ID]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Groups_ID] in table 'Video'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Video]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_VideoGroup]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Groups_ID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Groups]
        ([ID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_VideoGroup'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_VideoGroup]
ON [dbo].[Video]
    ([Groups_ID]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Creator_UserId] in table 'VideoComment'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VideoComment]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CommentUser]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Creator_UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User]
        ([UserId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_CommentUser'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_CommentUser]
ON [dbo].[VideoComment]
    ([Creator_UserId]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [User_UserId] in table 'VideoViewcount'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VideoViewcount]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_UserVideoViewcount]
    FOREIGN KEY ([User_UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User]
        ([UserId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_UserVideoViewcount'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_UserVideoViewcount]
ON [dbo].[VideoViewcount]
    ([User_UserId]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Creator_UserId] in table 'Video'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Video]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_UserVideo]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Creator_UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User]
        ([UserId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_UserVideo'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_UserVideo]
ON [dbo].[Video]
    ([Creator_UserId]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Members_UserId] in table 'UserGroup'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserGroup]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_UserGroup_User]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Members_UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User]
        ([UserId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Groups_ID] in table 'UserGroup'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserGroup]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_UserGroup_Group]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Groups_ID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Groups]
        ([ID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_UserGroup_Group'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_UserGroup_Group]
ON [dbo].[UserGroup]
    ([Groups_ID]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Creator_UserId] in table 'Groups'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Groups]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_UserGroup1]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Creator_UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User]
        ([UserId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_UserGroup1'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_UserGroup1]
ON [dbo].[Groups]
    ([Creator_UserId]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [AbsentUsers_UserId] in table 'AbsentUsers'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AbsentUsers]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AbsentUsers_User]
    FOREIGN KEY ([AbsentUsers_UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User]
        ([UserId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [AbsentDays_ID] in table 'AbsentUsers'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AbsentUsers]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_AbsentUsers_Presence]
    FOREIGN KEY ([AbsentDays_ID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Presence]
        ([ID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_AbsentUsers_Presence'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_AbsentUsers_Presence]
ON [dbo].[AbsentUsers]
    ([AbsentDays_ID]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [PresentUsers_UserId] in table 'PresentUsers'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PresentUsers]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_PresentUsers_User]
    FOREIGN KEY ([PresentUsers_UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User]
        ([UserId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [PresentDays_ID] in table 'PresentUsers'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PresentUsers]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_PresentUsers_Presence]
    FOREIGN KEY ([PresentDays_ID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Presence]
        ([ID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_PresentUsers_Presence'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_PresentUsers_Presence]
ON [dbo].[PresentUsers]
    ([PresentDays_ID]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [ExcusedUsers_UserId] in table 'ExcusedUsers'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExcusedUsers]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ExcusedUsers_User]
    FOREIGN KEY ([ExcusedUsers_UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User]
        ([UserId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [ExcusedDays_ID] in table 'ExcusedUsers'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ExcusedUsers]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_ExcusedUsers_Presence]
    FOREIGN KEY ([ExcusedDays_ID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Presence]
        ([ID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_ExcusedUsers_Presence'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_ExcusedUsers_Presence]
ON [dbo].[ExcusedUsers]
    ([ExcusedDays_ID]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Group_ID] in table 'File'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[File]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_FileGroup]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Group_ID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Groups]
        ([ID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_FileGroup'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_FileGroup]
ON [dbo].[File]
    ([Group_ID]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Creator_UserId] in table 'File'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[File]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_FileUser]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Creator_UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User]
        ([UserId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_FileUser'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_FileUser]
ON [dbo].[File]
    ([Creator_UserId]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [File_ID] in table 'FileViewcount'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FileViewcount]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_FileViewcountFile]
    FOREIGN KEY ([File_ID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[File]
        ([ID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_FileViewcountFile'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_FileViewcountFile]
ON [dbo].[FileViewcount]
    ([File_ID]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [User_UserId] in table 'FileViewcount'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FileViewcount]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_UserFileViewcount]
    FOREIGN KEY ([User_UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User]
        ([UserId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_UserFileViewcount'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_UserFileViewcount]
ON [dbo].[FileViewcount]
    ([User_UserId]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Creator_UserId] in table 'FileFolder'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FileFolder]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CategoryUser]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Creator_UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User]
        ([UserId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_CategoryUser'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_CategoryUser]
ON [dbo].[FileFolder]
    ([Creator_UserId]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Folder_ID] in table 'File'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[File]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_FileCategoryFile]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Folder_ID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[FileFolder]
        ([ID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_FileCategoryFile'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_FileCategoryFile]
ON [dbo].[File]
    ([Folder_ID]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Video_ID] in table 'VideoComment'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VideoComment]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_VideoVideoComment]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Video_ID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Video]
        ([ID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_VideoVideoComment'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_VideoVideoComment]
ON [dbo].[VideoComment]
    ([Video_ID]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [File_ID] in table 'FileComment'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FileComment]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_FileFileComment]
    FOREIGN KEY ([File_ID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[File]
        ([ID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_FileFileComment'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_FileFileComment]
ON [dbo].[FileComment]
    ([File_ID]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Creator_UserId] in table 'FileComment'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FileComment]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_UserFileComment]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Creator_UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User]
        ([UserId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_UserFileComment'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_UserFileComment]
ON [dbo].[FileComment]
    ([Creator_UserId]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Category_ID] in table 'Video'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Video]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_VideoCategoryVideo]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Category_ID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[VideoCategory]
        ([ID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_VideoCategoryVideo'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_VideoCategoryVideo]
ON [dbo].[Video]
    ([Category_ID]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Creator_UserId] in table 'VideoCategory'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[VideoCategory]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_VideoCategoryUser]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Creator_UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User]
        ([UserId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_VideoCategoryUser'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_VideoCategoryUser]
ON [dbo].[VideoCategory]
    ([Creator_UserId]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Opponent_ID] in table 'Video'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Video]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_OpponentVideo]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Opponent_ID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Opponent]
        ([ID])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_OpponentVideo'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_OpponentVideo]
ON [dbo].[Video]
    ([Opponent_ID]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Creator_UserId] in table 'Opponent'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Opponent]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_OpponentUser]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Creator_UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User]
        ([UserId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_OpponentUser'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_OpponentUser]
ON [dbo].[Opponent]
    ([Creator_UserId]);
GO

-- Creating foreign key on [Creator_UserId] in table 'News'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[News]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_NewsUser]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Creator_UserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[User]
        ([UserId])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

-- Creating non-clustered index for FOREIGN KEY 'FK_NewsUser'
CREATE INDEX [IX_FK_NewsUser]
ON [dbo].[News]
    ([Creator_UserId]);
GO

-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Script has ended
-- --------------------------------------------------
```

This is my _AppStart.cshtml

```
@using Coding.Lizards.Video.Manager.Web.Models;
@{
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "User", "UserId", "Emailaddress", autoCreateTables: true);
    WebsiteModel model = new WebsiteModel();
    if (!Roles.GetAllRoles().Contains("addgroup")) {
        Roles.CreateRole("addgroup");
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding `UserId` property to your anonymous class in `WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount` `propertyValues`? Set it to 0, like this: `new { UserId = 0, Firstname = model.FirstName, ... }`

Comment: Can you post the code for the method WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider.IsUserInRole(String username, String roleName)? The stack trace indicates the problem lies there, most likely with the command text which it is generating and passing to  WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseWrapper.QuerySingle(String commandText, Object[] parameters)

Comment: This method is Microsoft code ;) And adding the UserId property by hand didn't worked, cause it is in identity mode

Comment: I added the _AppStart.cshtml. Maybe it helps

Comment: You could try using SQL profiler to get the problem SQL that is generated. It might give us a clue what is wrong.

Comment: I think I found the problem. The EntityDesigner creates the properties `[webpages_Roles_RoleId]` and `[UserProfile_UserId]` but they should be called `[RoleId]` and `[UserId]`. So how can I change this?

Comment: I think you just need to change your create script. I've added an answer below because comments don't support formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the create script for webpages_UsersInRolesto this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_UsersInRoles] (
    [RoleId] int  NOT NULL,
    [UserId] int  NOT NULL
);
```

In case you were interested, I used reflection to look at the method throwing the exception, and it looks like this:

```
internal static string UsersInRoleTableName
{
  get
  {
    return "webpages_UsersInRoles";
  }
}


List<object> list = Enumerable.ToList<object>(database.Query("SELECT u." + this.SafeUserNameColumn + " FROM " + this.SafeUserTableName + " u, " + SimpleRoleProvider.UsersInRoleTableName + " ur, " + SimpleRoleProvider.RoleTableName + " r Where (r.RoleName = @0 and ur.RoleId = r.RoleId and ur.UserId = u." + this.SafeUserIdColumn + " and u." + this.SafeUserNameColumn + " LIKE @1)", (object) roleName, (object) usernameToMatch));
```

You should then be able to change the property names in your Entity Framework model, either by refreshing the model from the database, or editing the property names directly in the designer. In VS2010, you can click on the property, and then either click again to edit it (just like changing a file name in explorer), or change the name in the properties pane.

Comment: Worked great :) Is it possible to change the name of the columns in EntityDesigner?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by enabling migrations in my project and then executing my project after the following steps.

1. Delete the database of your project
2. Go to Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console
3. PM>`Enable-Migrations`
4. PM>`Update-Database`

The database along with the table containing the required columns will be created, provided that you configure the connection string in Web.Config of your project.